# C Segmentation fault in a recursive function

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse a square matrix by using Gauss method and it works with matrix of little size, less than 100x100, but with bigger matrices like 500x500 i got a segmentation fault.

I understand that I don't allocate enough memory for the matrix but I don't know why. I've tried with malloc and calloc but both give the same result. Also when I did some tests to know when the program stops because of the segmentation fault it happened that it doesn't stop in the same recursion of my function each times.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Create a matrix with random value between 0 and 99
double **generate_matrix(int size)
{
    int i;

    double **matrix;

    //This part is just to allocate memory space for the matrix
    matrix = (double **)malloc( size* sizeof(double*));

    for(int n=0; n<size; n++){
      matrix[n] = (double *) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    }


    //init the random
    srand(1);

    //For each element of the matrix give value between 0 and 99
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
          matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
      }
    }
    //return the matrix
    return matrix;
}


//Create identity matrix
double ** MatId(int size){
      double ** id;
      int n,i,j;
      //This part is just to allocate memory space for the matrix
      id = (double**) malloc( size* sizeof(double*));
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        id[i] = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
      }


      for(i=0;i<size;i++){
              for(j=0; j<size; j++){
                      if(i==j){
                              id[i][j] = 1;
                      }
                      else{
                            id[i][j] = 0;
                      }
              }
      }
      return(id);
}



//reverse the matrix tfloat_mat and give the result in tfloat_inv by using Gauss Pivot method,
//tfloat_inv is initialized by identity matrix
//int_ligne and int_collone initialized at 0.
//int_taille size of the matrix

double ** inverseGauss(double ** tfloat_mat, double ** tfloat_inv, int int_ligne, int int_colonne, int int_taille){
  int i;//Variable of loop
  double float_case;//Value of the treated element
  float_case = tfloat_mat[int_ligne][int_colonne];


  //If the element is on the diagonal
  if(int_ligne == int_colonne){
    //If the value is 0 we are blocked
    if(float_case == 0){
      printf("Not reversible with Gauss method \n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    //If the value is not 1 we have to modify it
    if(float_case != 1){
      //Gauss algorithm
      for(i = 0; i < int_taille; i++){
        tfloat_mat[int_ligne][i] = (tfloat_mat[int_ligne][i])/float_case;
        tfloat_inv[int_ligne][i] = (tfloat_inv[int_ligne][i])/float_case;
      }
    }
    //Changment of element of the matrix
    if((int_ligne == int_taille - 1) && (int_colonne == int_taille - 1)){
      return(inverseGauss(tfloat_mat, tfloat_inv, 0, 1, int_taille));
    }
    else{
      return(inverseGauss(tfloat_mat, tfloat_inv, int_ligne + 1, int_colonne, int_taille));
    }
  }


  //If the element is in the lower triangle we do an other part of Gauss algorithm
  else if((int_colonne < int_taille)&&(int_ligne > int_colonne)){
    if(float_case != 0){
      for(i = 0; i < int_taille; i++){
        tfloat_mat[int_ligne][i] = (tfloat_mat[int_ligne][i])-float_case*tfloat_mat[int_colonne][i];
        tfloat_inv[int_ligne][i] = (tfloat_inv[int_ligne][i])-float_case*tfloat_inv[int_colonne][i];
      }
    }
    //Changment of element of the matrix
    if(int_ligne == int_taille - 1){
      return(inverseGauss(tfloat_mat, tfloat_inv, int_colonne + 1, int_colonne + 1, int_taille));
    }
    else{
      return(inverseGauss(tfloat_mat, tfloat_inv, int_ligne + 1, int_colonne, int_taille));
    }
  }

    //If the element is in the upper triangle of the matrix we do an other part of Gauss algotithm
  else{
    if(float_case != 0){
      for(i = 0; i < int_taille; i++){
        tfloat_mat[int_ligne][i] = (tfloat_mat[int_ligne][i])-float_case*tfloat_mat[int_colonne][i];
        tfloat_inv[int_ligne][i] = (tfloat_inv[int_ligne][i])-float_case*tfloat_inv[int_colonne][i];
      }
    }
    //Changment of element of the matrix
    if((int_colonne == int_taille - 1)&&(int_ligne == int_taille -2)){
      //Here we did all the step so we return the reverse matrix
      return(tfloat_inv);
    }
    else if(int_ligne +1 != int_colonne){
      return(inverseGauss(tfloat_mat, tfloat_inv, int_ligne + 1, int_colonne, int_taille));
    }
    else{
      return(inverseGauss(tfloat_mat, tfloat_inv, 0, int_colonne + 1, int_taille));
    }
  }
}



//Print the matrix
void PrintMat(int size, double ** matrix){
  int i;//Variable of loop, row of the matrix
  int j;//Variable of loop, column of the matrix
  //print row per row
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
      printf("%f ", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}




int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int size = atoi(argv[1]);
  //identity matrix
  double ** id = MatId(size);
  //matrix with random value
  double ** mat=generate_matrix(size);


  //reverse matrix of intial mat
  mat = inverseGauss(mat, id, 0,0,size);


//free memory
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    free(mat[i]);
  }
  free(mat);

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    free(id[i]);
  }
  free(id);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect `inverseGauss()` is being called with indexes out of range.  Consider some `assert()`s with `int_ligne, int_colonne, int_taille`.

Comment: @chux True, but you should probably give some reference. People don't necessary know about floating-point comparison.
For instance: https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf

Comment: @chux Your comment was fine. OP should not compare a floating point value with `==`. But better to tell him why IMHO ; )

Comment: Multiply `500*500*sizeof(void *)` and see what you get. Then compare that with the amount of memory you have on your system. Comprende?

Comment: Start by adding error checking to your code. For example, you should check every call to `malloc` to see if it returns `NULL`. You should also use a debugger to see where the fault is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @chux by out of range, do you mean bigger than the size of the matrix ? Because when I print int_ligne and int_colonne for each recursion the program stops around int_ligne = 99 and int_colonne = 106 so I don't think that is a out of range problem :/

Comment: @JL2210 I am a beginner so I am not sure but I've tried  to see the amount of memory with the command "cat /proc/meminfo" and I think that I have enough memory t do it.

Comment: Well, usually only a portion of that is part of the stack. A better option would be to refactor your code to not use recursion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am doing these tests on my code it doesn't return NULL for sure. I used a debugger but as it is a recursive function gdb didn't help because the program don't stop in the same recursion each times.

Comment: @JL2210 yes I can also try without it thank you for your help.

Comment: Debugger, use it.

Comment: It may be helpful to change `float_case = tfloat_mat[int_ligne][int_colonne];` to use `malloc` as well. Otherwise, there's no good way to tell if the allocation fails.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all the help, I did a new program without recursive function and it works well now.